# Custom property drawer resulting in "NullReferenceException: : SerializedProperty is null"

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've tried to basically implement this straight from Unity's provided template for property drawers, which I am very new to. Simply trying to display enum properties from a custom class in the inspector, which should show up as drop down menus.

```
    [CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(InputAxis))]
    public class InputAxisDrawer : PropertyDrawer
    {
        private int _col1Width = 100;
        private int _col2Width = 80;

        public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
        {
            EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);

            // Draw label
            position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(position, GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive), label);

            // Don't make child fields be indented
            var indent = EditorGUI.indentLevel;
            EditorGUI.indentLevel = 0;

            // Calculate rects
            var EventRect = new Rect(position.x, position.y, _col1Width, position.height);
            var AxisRect = new Rect(position.x + _col1Width, position.y, _col2Width, position.height);

            // Draw fields - pass GUIContent.none to each so they are drawn without labels
            EditorGUI.PropertyField(EventRect, property.FindPropertyRelative("InputEvent"), GUIContent.none);
            EditorGUI.PropertyField(AxisRect, property.FindPropertyRelative("Axis"), GUIContent.none);

            // Set indent back to what it was
            EditorGUI.indentLevel = indent;

            EditorGUI.EndProperty();
        }
    }
```

Instead of working, I get the error (in title) for both properties. The property names match up as they should, and namespaces shouldn't be a problem (not sure if that's relevant here). Here's a corresponding visual from the inspector. Any ideas?

[current property drawer display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgafZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Alright false alarm. The custom class was still inheriting from MonoBehaviour, which was the cause of the problem. Leaving this up in case it can save anyone else a head scratch in future.